# Max(set) in function gives type error in Jupyter

Tags: python, recursion, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

Running this function in Jupyther notebook to get the max value of a collatz sequence

```
def collatz_max(i, seq = set()):
    seq.add(i)
    if i == 1:
        return max(seq)
    else:
        if i%2 == 0:
            return collatz_max(i/2, seq)
        else:
            return collatz_max(3*i + 1, seq)

collatz_max(7)
```

yields

```
    <ipython-input-64-2d2324774edf> in collatz_max(i, seq)
      6     seq.add(i)
      7     if i == 1:
----> 8         return max(seq)
      9     else:
     10         if i%2 == 0:

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

However, there was no error when I ran this in PyCharm, so I am not sure why exactly  it is there?

Comment: You've assigned `max = dict(...)` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you have defined a dictionary with the name `max`. Rename the dictionary to a name that's not already taken by a builtin.

Comment: Oh... should have realized that. Thanks